# `gsutil equivalent` missing in GCP User Interface

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-console

I am doing a tutorial on `Google Certified Associate Cloud Engineer 2020`, which used to be on `Udemy` and now is on `Cloud Guru`. I am watching a video on `GCS: Google Cloud Storage.`

At one point tutor, while using GCP User Interface, is renaming a file. In the window `Rename Object`, a great feature shows `gsutil equivalent`. [image]

This `gsutil equivalent` is not showing on my GCP User Interface. Is there any option to turn this on, or is this a feature that no longer exists?

I have tried to look at different options in User Interface, but I cannot find the option I am looking for. I have tried to Google this, but most things that come up are more related to `gsutil` itself rather than User Interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to your question if you have to activate something to be able to get this feature, the answer is that you don’t have to activate  anything as there is no way to activate it because this is a feature from the GCP UI interface that has been changed since the video that you used as a reference was released.

If you want to get the same `gsutil` command you would be able if you click on **move** option instead of using **rename**. This will open another window where you would find the same `gsutil` command as you found in the image that you shared.

[image]

The reason why the same command is present in the **move** option as it was in the **rename** is because in the end a **rename** the same as a **move**, which is in fact a 2-step process: a **copy** and a **delete**, as can be seen in the steps to rename using the REST API as described in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#rest-rename-object).

In the case that you want this feature to be again available on the GCP UI you can always open a Feature Request in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) asking for it.

Comment: awsome, thanks for the great answer, the tutorial begins with `Rename` and I assumed that that the feature is gone, I am glad it is only for `Rename` option, thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Rename feature is also available in GCP Console Just Chek following screenshots**

Check This :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8pyW.png

Comment: I think the OP is asking if the recommendation for the equivalent gsutil command still exists and not if the rename feature exists.

Comment: Yes @John Hanley, this is what I have been asking for:)